# Connect Power BI Excel file in Box

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have an Excel file that contains some sheets. I want to bring the Excel data into Power BI, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Home/Get Data/Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVnwu.png)

You can also do this when PBI is started in the "Get Data" option.